# How to remove the white space on right side of an image in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using **Bootstrap v3.3.0** for my website.

I'm showing an image into a bootstrap modal. But I'm getting extra white space on the right side of an image into a bootstrap modal dialog. I tried several CSS tricks by setting width to auto/fix size, setting left and right margin to auto, etc. but couldn't succeed so asking for help.

Following is my bootstrap modal code.

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: -20.5px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">
          Rebate Receipt
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 420px; overflow: auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <img class="img-responsive" style="text-align:center;" src="http://55.220.5.82:80/Students/2014_Q4/student_123343445434.png"></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The screen-shot is attached below :
[image: In the screen shot you can see the white space appearing on right side of an image. I want to remove that white space by using inline css.]

Thanks.

Comment: Check if width is set to the image.

Comment: @anpsmn:I've not set the width of the image. But the bootstrap modal dialog is taking width of 479px from Bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your css

```
.modal-dialog {
    width:auto;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
.modal {
    text-align: center;
}
.modal:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
}
.modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-dialog{
    width:auto;
}
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9387/

Comment: @Gorostas add `.modal-body{padding-right:30px}` to fix left and right padding

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bqffdw57/5/

```
$('#myModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //get image width
    //+30 = padding left and right for .modal-body
    //+20 = the approximate width of the scrollbar
    var w=$('#img').width()+30+20;

    $('.modal-dialog').width(w);
})
```